# How to Teleport a mouse (not MouseMove) in ahk?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to play games using a remote desktop software called rustdesk and I have created a script to move mouse 360 degrees in horizontal manner but as soon as the mouse goes from left to right the character in the game also moves so how to MoveMouse without seeing those changes in rustdesk.

This is the code:

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, check, -100
return

check(){
    If edge("left")
    {
        MouseMove, 1718, 490, 0
        
    }
    else if edge("right")
    {
        MouseMove, 0, 490, 0
        
    }

    ; ...

    SetTimer, check, -100
}

edge(pos){
    SysGet, VirtualWidth, 78
    SysGet, VirtualHeight, 79
    T := 10 
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, mX, mY
    left := (mX < T)
    top := (mY < T)
    right := (mX > VirtualWidth - T)
    bottom := (mY > VirtualHeight - T)
    If (pos = "left")
        return left
    else if (pos = "top")
        return top
    else if (pos = "right")
        return right
    else if (pos = "bottom")
        return bottom
}
```

```
I tried using BlockInput but it completely stops the mouse.
```